# Mod_wsgi can't run mkfifo?

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

I am trying to run a mod_wsgi application on RHEL6, and I can't seem to make a FIFO no matter how I try. I think it may be a permissions issue, but I can't figure it out.

Here's the relevant part of the httpd config:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess loris user=loris group=loris processes=10 threads=15 maximum-requests=10000
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
WSGIProcessGroup loris

<Directory /var/www/loris>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Here's a minimum working example (Python 2.7):

```
import getpass
import os
import subprocess

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain')]

    path = '/var/www/loris'

    c = ''
    c += 'user: %s\n' % getpass.getuser() # prints 'loris', as expected

    # try opening a file; works fine
    f = open('%s/open.txt' % path, 'w')
    f.write('ok\n')
    f.close()
    c += 'we can write a file\n'

    # try 'touching' a file; works fine
    call = '/bin/touch %s/touch.txt' % path
    s = subprocess.check_call(call, shell=True)
    c += '/bin/touch status = %s' % s    # prints 0, as expected

    # try shelling out to mkfifo; doesn't work
    # Error msg: '/usr/bin/mkfifo: cannot create fifo `/var/www/loris/binfifo':
    #   Permission denied'
    call = '/usr/bin/mkfifo %s/binfifo' % path
    s = subprocess.check_call(call, shell=True)
    # throws a 500 error

    # try os.mkfifo(); doesn't work either
    fifo_path = '%s/os_fifo' % path
    os.mkfifo(fifo_path)
    s = subprocess.check_call(call, shell=True)
    # again, 'OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied'

    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return c
```

Clearly the user has permissions to write to the directory, but it's looking like `mkfifo` in particular is a problem (since `/bin/touch` works fine). I can make a fifo as myself, so the filesystem supports them. I can also make fifos in both ways (shelling out and `os.mkfifo()`) in a python shell as user `loris`. I think it has something to do with mod_wsgi and permissions, but I can't think of what else to try.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ls -l /var/www/loris /var/www/loris/binfifo`?

Comment: The file `/var/www/loris/binfifo` doesn't exist (that's the problem!). The directory is owned by `loris:loris`.

Comment: Still I would very much like to see the output of the above command; don't worry, `ls` will not crash if you ask it to list a non-existing file. Actually, make it `ls -ld /var/www/loris /var/www/loris/binfifo`

Comment: `ls: cannot access /var/www/loris/bininfo: No such file or directory`, and then
`drwxr-xr-x. loris loris 4096 Jan 15 21:19 /var/www/loris` (can't get newlines to show up in the markup).

Comment: Very weird indeed. Are you running on Linux? Can you try to replace `'/usr/bin/mkfifo %s/binfifo'` with `'/bin/mknod %s/binfifo p'`? I take it `os.mkfifo` also fails?

Comment: I'm running Red Hat 6, yes. `/bin/mknod` gives the same error (permission denied), and `os.mkfifo()` also fails. All of these things work from a python shell, however, it's just failing when run with mod-wsgi.

Comment: Can you try `subprocess.check_output('id')` _inside WSGI_? It might be running under some other user identity for some reason.

Comment: YARGH! That didn't fix it, but it does confirm that the problem is with the extended permissions. It's running as the right user and group, but the context under WSGI is `unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0`, and in a shell it's `unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:20-20:c0.c1023`. It seems like `httpd_t` can't make fifos...now I just need to figure out how to fix that.

Comment: Are you running with SELinux extensions enabled? That will restrict what you can and can't do and where.